# jQuery - Change Background Image With Variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a CSS background image with jQuery but can't seem to figure out how.  I THINK I'm along the right lines but I'm not sure...

```
var bgImg = "http://www.domain.com/my-image.jpg";

$('#myBanner').css("background", "url("+bgImg+");");
```

Here's a fiddle of it not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/qLqvtkp3/

Any help would be great!!

Comment: Remove the `;` in the string

Comment: ^^ This.  All the other answers are overkill and not highlighting the actual problem.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon You should post it as an answer so he can accept it.  It's the only clear explanation on the page.

Comment: @Archer alright, just did it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the `;` in the string. it make the rule invalid and jQuery doesn't add invalid rule in the `style` attribute.

```
$('#myBanner').css("background", "url("+bgImg+")");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qLqvtkp3/17/

Comment: +1, Good spotting, I thought along with css color etc, OP wanted background image then it should be background-image.

Comment: @SSA it depend, he may want to override the entire background property. In other word, doesn't want the pink background.

Comment: Exactly, I thought it differently then you did. You already got +1 from me for spotting ';'.

Comment: @SSA And i'm thankful for that! Anyway, it is good to mention it so the OP know the possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
$('#myBanner').css({
                "background-image": "url('" + bgImg + "')"
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLqvtkp3/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Replace `background` with  `background-image`

```
$('#myBanner').css("background-image","url('"+bgImg+"')");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Problems in your code :-

1)-You have **concatenated** your strings in the wrong way.

2)-You used **background** .You should use **background-image**.

3)-You have written `;`  in your jQuery css code ( `"url("+bgImg+");")` )

Try this :-

```
 var bgImg = "http://www.domain.com/my-image.jpg";

 $('#myBanner').css({"background-image":"url('"+bgImg+"')"});
```

Comment: cummon ..then what should be the solution ..you tell @Karl-AndréGagnon

Comment: See my comment on the question!

Comment: yeah .. but i wrote it correct @Karl-AndréGagnon . Why you downvoted ?

Comment: Totally incorrect syntax.  It should either be an object (wrapped with {}) or 2 parameters.  In fact, the only thing wrong with the code in the original question is the trailing `;` in the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Pay closer attention - it uses object notation.

Comment: Well, now you're right about the `;`, but the syntax is wrong. See archer comment